# how to make dynamic change in worlflow definition

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am using liferay 6.1.1CE.

Am using kaleo as my workflow engine.

As of my knowledge,the workflow is uploaded as a xml file . and i did that(upload a workflow with 2 levels of approvel).

my question is,  can we dynamically change the roles,user ids in that workflow through a user interface that is provided to a particular user in my portal?

2ng thing is

for eg: i have a portlet that is common to all users,In my portal 2 user groups are there.

Different approval criteria for both groups.
so i can create two type of workflow for the two groups.

my question is,based on the user ( in which group) can i redirect the portlet to the corresponding workflow...?

share your suggestions..Is it possible or not?